# Get sum of time in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table tblTimesheet in which I store user timing hours, like this:

```
Hours
4.01
3.44
0.05
0.04
2.40
```

What I want is some of these time periods I am using this

```
select sum(hours) from tbltimesheets
where workDate='2012-08-30 00:00:00.000' and taskid in (86,3,34)
```

but it's giving me 9.94, and I want to get it like 10.34; the datatype is **decimal** of this field.

Comment: What is the data type of `Hours` column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Hrs FLOAT
)
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 4.01 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 3.44 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 0.05 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 0.04 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 2.40

;WITH Vals AS (
        SELECT  SUM(FLOOR(Hrs)) NumHrs,
                SUM((Hrs - FLOOR(Hrs)) * 100) NumMins 
        FROM    @Table
)
SELECT  NumHrs + FLOOR(NumMins / 60) + ((NumMins / 60 - FLOOR(NumMins / 60)) * 60 / 100)
FROM    Vals
```

Comment: can't we do this without making a temp table

Comment: please provide example of that as i can't use temp table

Comment: Just use the same functionality as above but with your table and columns and criteria.

Answer (score 0):

First hours conet to minute and last step divide by 60.

```
select (sum(hours*60)/60) from tbltimesheets
where workDate='2012-08-30 00:00:00.000' and taskid in (86,3,34)
```